# Microsoft Excel - define a "string" to get specific output

Tags: excel

A friend of mine works at Verizon and asked me If excel has built in functions for whenever he types "open" into a cell it will return "8:30-5:00" into that cell.

I hounded google for an hour. I cant seem to find what I am looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible via VBA. And VBA is a build in feature. So yes, excel does have something like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom functions in Excel. Custom functions, like macros, use the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) programming language.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Worksheet Event Macro](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Events.aspx).  This is a small routine that will constaintly monitor cells on a worksheet and take action if data is typed into them.
Say we want to monitor cell **B9**.  Include the following in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim B9 As Range

    Set B9 = Range("B9")
    If Intersect(Target, B9) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If B9.Value <> "Open" Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        B9.Value = "8:30-5:00"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

A non-VBA solution is possible using Excel's built-in Autocorrect facility.

On the File tab in Excel 2013 click Options -> Proofing -> Autocorrect and enter "open" in the Replace: box and "8:30-5:00" in the With: box (without the quotes).

This is not case sensitive so will work for both "open" and "Open".

If you are ever likely to want "open" or "Open" to appear in a string you could add an escape character such as backslash to your replace string "\open".

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.